# Where do I find drivers for 14.04.1 on Dell Inspirion 1720?

Tags: drivers

Where do I find drivers for 14.04.1 on Dell Inspirion 1720?

I loaded this version of Ubuntu today and it will not let me get on the internet. It seems this version is missing drivers for my Dell Inspirion 1720.

Comment: You're not really giving us enough. Which interface are you trying to use: Ethernet or WiFi?

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285338/ubuntu-wont-detect-my-dell-1395-wlan-mini-wireless-card

Comment: I would like to set up both Ethernet and WiFi.

What is curious is that I have the same distro on another machine which I am using now to post this query.  On this Dell Optiplex 755 the internet works great.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of the newer distros will work fine with any drivers.  BUT during the install the naming can get messed up.  In Kubuntu you do the following:

If Network Management is “unmanaged”
This is a common problem going to 13.10 and going to 14.04.
/etc/Network Manager/NetworkManager.conf
change managed =false to managed=true

/etc/network/interfaces
Make sure the following lines are there with nothing else:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Walt, I am not clear on what you are instructing me to do. I am a newby to Ubuntu. I must find a way to get on the internet with my Dell Inspirion 1720. What do you suggest? When doing a hard boot the boot process seems to be looking for various drivers, thus my question.